# How to declare UserId to add to new table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I want to check the query in sqlserver but I have an error `Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.`

```
Declare @UserId nVarchar='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'
Declare @PersonId int=936;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users_Emps] ([UserId],[EmpId]) (SELECT distinct      
CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,@UserId),Employee.EmpId FROM Employee 
inner join Users_Emps ON Employee.EmpId = Users_Emps.EmpId where 
PersonId=@PersonId)
```

[image]
I take the parameters from the code behind

```
 DsUsers_Emps.InsertParameters["UserId"].DefaultValue =
 Membership.GetUser(UserName.Text).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    DsUsers_Emps.InsertParameters["PersonId"].DefaultValue=PersonsDropDownList.SelectedValue;
    DsUsers_Emps.Insert();
```

Answer (score 1):

Always specify size:

```
Declare @UserId NVARCHAR(100)='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80';

SELECT CAST(@UserId AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);
```

Using:

```
Declare @UserId NVARCHAR;

/* Is the same as */

Declare @UserId NVARCHAR(1);
```

And your `@UserId = '3'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @UserId nVarchar='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'
```

In above piece of code snippet you have declared variable **@UserID** as **nVarchar**, Here you didn't mentioned any length to it by default it's **1**. So if following statement is executed it will return `3` as result istead of `'3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'`.

```
Select @UserId as 'UserID'
```

Now, Here you are trying to convert @UserID into  **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER**. For conversion we require a character string of format

`xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

but the one generate by

```
Declare @UserId nVarchar='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'
```

is x. Therefore, the conversion failed.

As mentioned by **@lad2025**, Specify size either 50, 100 or 255. Give your nVarchar datatype a fixed length.

```
 Declare @UserId nVarchar(50)='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'
```

or

```
Declare @UserId nVarchar(255)='3847609f-6fd1-4a14-9675-000d74a5df80'
```

It will work now.

**Reference:** [nVarchar vs nVarchar(n)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms186939.aspx) and [UniqueIdentifier](https://www.technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(v=sql.105).aspx)